# WordPress - array_merge() Error on Ajax call

Tags: php, wordpress

I really don't know why I am getting this error. I have a local development and my code works fine with same PHP version, same WordPress version, but then I got this on my staging development.

> Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /home/user/public_html/mydomain.com/wp-includes/load.php** on line 63

My Ajax code is fine, and the PHP has nothing to worry, but in staging site, the Ajax returns the warning and the data I set.

Update Codes:

Ajax

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: loi_ajax.ajax_url,
    data: {
        action: 'loi_ajax_listener',
        method: 'get_state_value',
        state_id: state_id
    },
    success: function( data ){

        var d = data.data;

        $('#state_info_editor').find('#state_name').text(d.name+' ('+ d.id +')');
        $('#state_info_editor').find('#state_id').val(d.id);

        if (typeof d.page != "undefined" && d.page.length == 2) {
            console.log(d.page);
            $('#state_info_editor').find('#state_select option[value='+d.page+']').attr("selected",true);
        }
        console.log(d);
        tb_show('Edit State', "#TB_inline?width=300&height=200&inlineId=state_info_editor");
    }
});
```

PHP is using oop so this is the method

```
public static function loi_ajax_listener()
{
    $return = array();

    //go to spesific method
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['method']) ) {
        $return = self::{$_REQUEST['method']}();
    }

    //status should always present either success or error
    wp_send_json_success($return);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: make sure both arguments are array.
array_merge($array1, $array2);

Comment: If your code was fine, you would not have errors. Share your code please.

Comment: just before array merge try dumping your second argument and check if it's an array or not. `var_dump($argument_two);`

Comment: You really should fix whatever's causing the warning, but you can control visibility of errors with error_reporting because that affect ajax. To skip warning messages, you could use something like:

`error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);`

Comment: @MuhammadUsama OP is not asking for error reporting

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for coming.. I just updated with code

Comment: @ShelðÔnAlag where's get_state_value method?

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru - it doesn't matter what method it points, I tried sending back the data from ajax and still have that array_merge thing.

Comment: @ShelðÔnAlag are you using IIS server or linux server? According to your error message, WordPress is having issues with PHP's `$_SERVER` https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/load.php#L66

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru - I was thinking this is a server side or something. the server on the staging site is using sitegrounds. linux base i guess.

Comment: @ShelðÔnAlag can you share the output of `var_dump($_SERVER);` from your staging

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru these are the server dump
`SERVER_SOFTWARE => Apache
REQUEST_URI => /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=states&page=svg-map-integration
PATH => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PHPHANDLER => /usr/local/php70/bin/php
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL => max-age=0
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
HTTP_ACCEPT => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE => en-US,en;q=0.9,fil;q=0.8
GATEWAY_INTERFACE => CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL => HTTP/1.0
QUERY_STRING => post_type=states&page=svg-map-integration
argc => 1`